# Using a KClass reference as a reified parameter to deserialize from JSON

Tags: json, kotlin, generics, kotlin-js, kotlinx.serialization

I'm trying to implement a general serialization framework to convert outgoing and incoming messages to json using the kotlinx serialialization. I'm developing a multiplatform app, so I'm trying to get it to run on KotlinJVM and KotlinJS.

For this, I add a `type` field to every message and use a map that maps each `type` string to a `KClass`. What's the type for that map? It contains `KClass<>` objects whose classes extend the Message class, therefore in java I'd specify my map as
`Map<KClass<? extends Message>, String>`.

How can I do that in Kotlin?

Afterwards I need to serialize and deserialize the message based on its key and therefore type. Java frameworks take a Class parameter for the type of the object I want to deserialize/instantiate (e.g. `gson.fromJson(ClientMessage.class)`). In Kotlin this is done using `reified` parameters `Json.decodeFromString<Type>`. I do not know the type of the message at compile time though and just have a reference to a `KClass`, how can I instantiate an object based on that?

```
@Serializable
open class Message(val type: String) {

    companion object {
        val messageTypes: Map<KClass<out Message>, String> = mapOf(
            ClientLoginMessage::class to "clientLoginMessage",
            Message::class to "message"
        )

        inline fun <reified T> getMessageTypeByClass(): String = messageTypes[T::class]!! // utility for defining the type in the constructors of the individual messages
    }

    fun toJson() = Json.encodeToString(this)

    fun fromJson(json: String): Message? {
        val plainMessage = Json.decodeFromString<Message>(json) // get type string from json
        return messageTypes.entries.find { it.value == plainMessage.type }?.let {
            // how can I use the KClass from it.key as reified parameter?
            Json.decodeFromString<?????>(json) 
        }
    }
}

@Serializable
class ClientLoginMessage
         : Message(Message.getMessageTypeByClass<ClientLoginMessage>()) {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a map of serializers like for types:

```kotlin
val serializers: Map<KClass<out Message>, KSerializer<out Message>> = mapOf(
            ClientLoginMessage::class to ClientLoginMessage.serializer(),
            Message::class to Message.serializer()
        )
```

Pass in the serializer needed to `Json.decodeFromString` like this:

```kotlin
fun fromJson(json: String): Message? {
        val plainMessage = Json.decodeFromString<Message>(json) // get type string from json
        return messageTypes.entries.find { it.value == plainMessage.type }?.let {
            // how can I use the KClass from it.key as reified parameter?
            Json.decodeFromString(serializers.get(plainMessage.type)!!, json)
        }
    }
```

You might also want to have a look at the Kotlin built in handling of polymorphic classes: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md

Comment: I ended up just using the built in polymorphism as you suggested, completely forgot about that from when I read the docs back then. Thanks for still answering my original question about how to do that for arbitrary classes though.